# How to find the man page for makefiles?

Tags: linux, manpage

I'm looking for the man pages of the `makefile`, and not the man pages of the `make` program.

The latter, I can find and read its man pages easily by running `man make`. But for the former, I cannot find any man pages on how to actually write a makefile. I've run `apropos make` on my Linux machine (Ubuntu) and I didn't find any reference to a man page for the actual makefiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen [this site](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)? It is extremely comprehensive, and the majority of the chapters are concerned with makefiles (rules, variables, functions, conventions, etc.) as opposed to `make` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try `apt install make-doc`

Followed by `info make`